# Flutter - macOS; app run but cannot archive

Tags: xcode, macos, flutter, build

I had a strange situation that when i run my app is running fine via command line (flutter run) or by using xCode.

But when I choose "Any Mac (Apple Silicon, Intel)" to archive, I got an error:

[image]

I tried different methods related with plugins problem, recommended in Github and here. For example, this one:

1. xCode -> Project -> Clean
2. deleted Podfile.lock and directory Pods
3. pod install
4. flutter clean, flutter run

Everything works smoothly until I try to archive.

This is my macOS Podfile:

```
platform :osx, '10.11'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'ephemeral', 'Flutter-Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure \"flutter pub get\" is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Flutter-Generated.xcconfig, then run \"flutter pub get\""
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_macos_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_macos_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_macos_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

This is the output of flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.26.0-2.0.pre.86, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H114 darwin-x64, locale en-IN)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Do anyone have any ideas what to do?

Thank you in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0):

```
flutter clean
rm Pods/ podfile.lock
pod deintegrate
pod install
flutter pub get
```

Then build your app again from xcode.